# android jetpack project gives archlifecycleversion build error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am new to android development and just created my first "hello world" project in android studio 3.2 ( canary ) following this tutorial.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started

and then I just did *Build- > make project* project tried to build and gave me following error.

> Could not get unknown property 'archLifecycleVersion' for root project 'JetpackHelloWorld' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

**UPDATE**

**Dependencies**

> following is the dependencies tag in my app folder build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion` with actual version, i guess this is 1.1.1 right now

Comment: I think I have both of them already please see the updated part of the question

Comment: then remove it, you cannot have twice the same lib :-/

Comment: ok sure ill remove and try to build again, but its strange bcz it was generated by default in the project. and without making any change to dependencies I got the build error.

Comment: ok that error was fixed with this way and now I have a new error : the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified

Answer (score 2):

In your app Gradle file (build.gradle, you should see "app" to its right), you probably have

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion'
```

Change it to:

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
```

or add this to the top of your implementation line

```
def archLifecycleVersion = 1.1.1
```

Comment: I think I have both of them already please see the updated part of the question

Answer (score 1):

I think part (if not all) of the code is taken from this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/

In the third part of the codelab, titled "Update gradle files" they use these lines (in the module's build.gradle) to import Room and Lifecycle components:

```
// Room components
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
```

So, these "roomVersion" and "archLifecycleVersion" are variables that you have to define in the main build.gradle file. In the example they use these values:

```
ext {
   roomVersion = '1.0.0'
   archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.0'
}
```

But I've actually used "1.1.1" for both variables and it works.