# android studio the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am new to android development and just created my first "hello world" project in android studio 3.2 ( canary ) following this tutorial. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started

and then I just did Build- > make project project tried to build and gave me following error.

> Could not get unknown property 'archLifecycleVersion' for root project 'JetpackHelloWorld' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

but I was able to solve that error with help of answers on a question I posted. 
[android jetpack project gives archlifecycleversion build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329891/android-jetpack-project-gives-archlifecycleversion-build-error)

after that error was solved I tried to build again and now I have the following error.

> the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified

**Update**

**Build.gradle** (app folder level )

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.touseef.jetpackhelloworld"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**build.gradle** (project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Run is disabled**

as you can see in the screenshot, run option of the app is disabled and it asks me to edit configuration if I click on the drop down, what kind of configurations I am supposed to do in a empty project?

[image: run disabled]

Comment: what's you kotlin version?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Please see the updated question , according to my dependencies I think I am pulling in the latest version of kotlin I think so.

Comment: The -d message is a warning, it does not prevent your project from working.

Comment: You're using a variable to tell the Kotlin version, kotlin_version, what's the value of this variable?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque where can I see this variable to see its value? actually this project was generated by the IDE so I dont really know where this variable is.

Comment: Probably in the project level build.gradle file

Comment: I cant see that variable in the file u specified @LeviAlbuquerque I have updated the question with the contents of that file and also a screenshot

Comment: @yole as you can see in the screenshot I provided the run option is disabled.

Comment: The disabled Run option has nothing to do with this message.

Comment: then why is it disabled? I mean how can I configure it to run? shouldnt it be preconfigured at time of project generation? @yole

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while building the project with `Kotlin` version `1.2.61`, it worked after updating the version to `1.2.71` from `1.2.61`

The classpath dependencies are(inside project level `build.gradle`) :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha10'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha06"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.2.71"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the problem is that in settings of Kotlin compiler activated incremental compilation. If you disable these options - you will not receive the warning.