# android jetpack getting started project cant run

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am new to android development and just created my first "hello world" project in android studio 3.2 ( canary ) following this tutorial. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started

and then I just did Build- > make project project tried to build and gave me following error.

> Could not get unknown property 'archLifecycleVersion' for root project 'JetpackHelloWorld' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

but I was able to solve that error with help of answers on a question I posted. 
[android jetpack project gives archlifecycleversion build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329891/android-jetpack-project-gives-archlifecycleversion-build-error)

after that error was solved I tried to build again and now I have the following error.

> the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified

**Run is disabled**

as you can see in the screenshot, run option of the app is disabled and it asks me to edit configuration if I click on the drop down, what kind of configurations I am supposed to do in a empty project?

[image: run disabled]

> but then I clicked on Edit Configurations and added a android application configuration, but at the point of selecting **modules** there was no modules in drop down list to select from, and now I cant run my app because i get the error "confuguration is not valid" I also see a red cross icon on my app name near the run button, I think that is because I have not selected a module? but how can I select one when there isnt any?

Comment: Try clicking that button two to the right of that rocket thing on the right (Gradle Sync) and see if that helps

Comment: it totally worked, please put it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking that button two to the right of that rocket thing on the right (Gradle Sync) and see if that helps